# Create batch file to find string in txt files and then delete the txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm looking for the correct syntax to make a batch file that finds a word in txt files and then deletes all the txt files with that word in it.

I've been using `findstr` to get the results but how do I manage to delete the files after that?

```
findstr -m "string" *txt | del
```

doesn't work

Should I use a variable or something?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't need recursive search you can try like this:

```
for %%a in (*txt) do (
   find /i "string" "%%~fa" >nul 2>nul &&(
      del /q /f "%%~fa"
   )
)
```